# JavaScript - Set timeout function, then get innerHTML and set sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I have a `<div>` called `resultsSection`. I want to set a timeout, wait 3 seconds, then get the contents of `resultsSection` and save it to `sessionStorage`.

I know this seems strange, but it's a simplified example. On my website, `resultsSection` has content loaded to it asynchronously from multiple sources. After everything is done loading into it (after around 3 seconds), then I want to copy `resultsSection`'s contents and save them in sessionStorage for later, so I don't have to reload everything again. I'm currently doing something wrong here. How do I achieve this?

```
<div class='resultsSection' id='resultsSection'>
    Example
</div>

<script>
    const itemName = "example";
    const name = "resultsSection";
    setTimeout(function(){ const data = document.getElementById(name).innerHTML;  }, 3000); // I think this is wrong
    sessionStorage.setItem(itemName , data );
</script>
```

Comment: Using `setTimeout` to compensate for async methods is inelegant. You do not know if it will always take only around 3 seconds for the data to be fetched. Instead the `sessionStorage` statements must be inside the async data handler that'll be executed after the data is fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a scoping problem. You set `data` inside of a function and attempted to use it outside. Instead, you need to call the function `setItem` *inside* of the function.

```
const itemName = "example";
const name = "resultsSection";
setTimeout(function() {
  const data = document.getElementById(name).innerHTML;  
  sessionStorage.setItem(itemName, data);
}, 3000);
```

Note that setTimeout *will not* delay the code after it. Everything that depends on the timeout **needs** to be inside of the timeout.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense. This is what I needed